# Selenium continue without loading page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

While I was doing testing in Eclipse, my java program has to wait for the page in Firefox driver to load completely. Is their any way that i can tell my program to continue executing the next step without waiting?

Comment: Without waiting how you will be able to find element in page?

Answer (score 1):

In my professional opinion, you shouldn't do this.  You should let Selenium do its duty, and make sure the page is fully loaded before you continue.

One thing to note, is that when you call `click()` on a WebElement, Selenium doesn't actually wait for the page to load.  `driver.get()` **does** however.

What you are asking, isn't a very "common practice", so this may or may not work.

Try just setting the pageLoadTimeout `"0"`.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

*(this syntax is of course if you are using Java. you don't have the question marked as a specific language, so take it as it is and convert it to your language of choice)*